# Signalr performance issues when deployed

Tags: asp.net, deployment, signalr

I have created a small real time app using asp.net and signalR. Everything seems to work fine when I test.

I open four clients to see the real time updates being issues. Yet when I host the application on my server, using the same laptop, i notice that the data in my app stops updating once I have more than two clients.

Using chrome, I tried to investigate the issue yet I am lost as to what I can do next. The Network developers tab indicates that POST request remain pending when I have more than two clients. Once I close the third client, all updates immediately take place.

What can the problem be?

Am I missing any configuration settings?

Is the deployment enviroment causing these issues?

My laptop has 6 gb of memory and has an i3 processor, so I am guessing that it can handle at least three connections. I used to have the same issue last year when I deployed another app on Go daddy it barely worked yet on Windows azure it worked perfectly.

Comment: What is your current configuration? Are you using IIS 7 + Windows 7? I've seen on the github issues that Windows 7 only allows 10 concurrent connections on IIS 7. If you use IIS express Win7 or use Windows Server will fix those issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm using IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Home Premium! Do you think that's the issue? Cheers!

Comment: What is GoDaddy's environment setup? It could be a configuration setup there since you mentioned it worked on azure perfectly. Also, you could try chatting with the devs on https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr to get some further info.